# NSMutableSet intput is not in the same order as output

Tags: objective-c, nsmutableset

I have added objects into a NSMutableSet with this code:

```
_theQuestionsSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc]initWithObjects:@802, @229, @522, @712, @628, @84, @412, @726, @284, @699, @1765, @1754, @1528, @2230, @2005, @1494, @1348, @2132, @2040, @2183, nil];
NSLog(@"%@", _theQuestionsSet);
```

Why is the output not in the same order as inserted?

```
2013-03-28 16:41:50.178 xxxxxxxx[4011:c07] {(
412,
1754,
628,
726,
1528,
284,
1348,
84,
2005,
699,
522,
712,
1494,
2132,
2230,
1765,
2040,
802,
2183,
229
)}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because an NSMutableSet has no order. An array is ordered; a set is not. (An ordered set sort of bridges the gap, but that's not what you're using.)

Read the fine documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html

What's the first sentence?

> The NSSet, NSMutableSet, and NSCountedSet classes declare the programmatic interface to an unordered collection of objects.

*Unordered*. End of story.

See also my book:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch10.html#_nsset_and_friends

> You can walk through (enumerate) a set with the `for...in` construct, though the order is of course undefined.

*The order is undefined*.

(It sounds from your original question as if what you really want is an NSMutableArray that you then shuffle. I have code for that! But that would be a different question.)

Comment: just ordered your book :-)

Answer (score 4):

Because it's not ordered. Use `NSMutableOrderedSet` if you need that.

Comment: He's not saying he wants it ordered, he's saying that the order that it was inserted is not the order it is held.

Comment: The notion of ordering in a set is meaningless.

Comment: Just so i understand if i insert objects in a specific order it will never come out sorted unless i am not using NSMutableOrderedSet? ...meaning i do not need to shuffle the objects?

Comment: @peterk Unordered is not shuffled;  if you need the objects shuffled, you will need an ordered collection AND you will need to shuffle them yourself.

Comment: @bbum I realized it when i tested, thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

NSMutableSet order is not maintained. Use NSMutableOrderedSet or NSMutableArray to maintain order